# Nginx Reverse Proxy's problematic behaviour

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a frontend running on port 80 and a backend running on port 8000 using a reverse proxy in nginx both of them are being connected from the same domain URL (eg. https://abc123.com it is an HTTPS ->ALB{aws}->http->nginx and https://abc123.com:8000 )using different ports most of the time port 8000 pages work on alternate hits i.e for first they show a 404 and when I reload it connects, on next reload it again shows 404 and so on. I have added caching but did not change anything. This port 8000 is routed to the backend Django server at 8001 port. Frontend is running perfectly. The backend is creating problems... How can I resolve this?

config looks like this:

server {

```
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;

    server_name  abc123.com 
  www.abc123.com;

    root        /var/www/test.abc.com/build;
    access_log /var/log/nginx /test_80/access.log  main buffer=16k;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/test_80/error.log notice;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
       }
   }




server{
    listen 8000;
    listen [::]:8000;

    server_name  abc123.com:8000  www.abc123.com:8000;
root   /app/abc-Backend/;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/test_8000/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test_8000/error.log notice;

    location / {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8001/;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:8001/ $scheme://$host:8000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_cache my_cache;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 304 10m;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS";
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization";

    }
```

As of now I am not using any WSGI(Gunicorn to be specific)

eg. For first abc123.com:8000/marvels show a 404 and when I reload it connects to the correct page, on next reload it again shows 404, and so on... similar case is for all the paths related to the Django backend.

Comment: Please include your Nginx configuration file in your question. Also, do you have more than one server running Nginx behind the load balancer? Or are the front-end and back-end running on a single server?

Comment: Hi Mark, I have added the nginx.conf server blocks. yes, they are running on a single Nginx server using different ports.

Comment: Can you show your load balancer's listener configuration? And can you verify that you have exactly _one_ target in the target group that handles the port `8000` requests? Seeing Nginx access logs would also be helpful in debugging this.

Comment: Thanks Mark.. I think I got it. The issue was at the listener target group. Thanks a ton.